# The as operator on structures?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, as-operator

I don't get it. The `As` operator:

[image: The as operator is used to perform certain types of conversions between compatible reference or nullable types.]

Then why does the following work?

```
struct Baby : ILive
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }

    public int Ggg() 
    {
        return Foo;
    }
}

interface ILive
{
    int Ggg();
}

void Main()
{
    ILive i = new Baby(){Foo = 1} as ILive;    // ??????
    Console.Write(i.Ggg());                    // Output: 1
}
```

- `Baby` is a struct, creating it will put value in `stack`. There is *no* reference involve here.
- There are certainly no nullable types here.

Any explanation as to why I'm wrong?

Comment: Btw, a mutable object like Baby makes a poor struct. A class would be a more obvious choice.

Comment: @MarcGravell of-course. but this question is for getting to know better  the edge scenarios. :-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Casting it as an interface will create a boxed copy on the managed heap , and return a reference to the boxed copy. The box implements the interface.

Comment: Doesnt the fact the interface do NOT inherit System.object , has anything to do with it ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir not in the least. Interfaces are always reference-types, with the slight exception of generics, when they can be *constrained* types (half-way between reference-type and value-type)

Answer (score 9):

It works because the right hand side is an interface. The condition is that the right hand side can accept `null` as value, i.e. it's a reference type or a nullable value type. Interfaces are a reference types. In this case the code will box the struct and then cast the boxed object to the interface.

Comment: Anything that has the static type of an interface, is a reference. If you cast a value type to an interface it gets boxed(giving you a reference). So in this context it's justified calling them reference types.

Comment: There is, as always, a *partial* exception to "anything": an interface when described via a generic constraint on some `T`. Although the "constrained" part only applies when the variable is `T` - *not* when it is the interface itself.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cast with reference type `ILive` nullable value, so no error is thrown. However if you try this commented code, you will get an error.

```
Baby b = new Baby ();
 object o = b;
//Baby bb = o as Baby ;
```

This is because you are trying to cast with `as` to value type and that can not be null.